# Querying a model based on its association using a class method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create an ActiveRecord query in Rails using multiple class methods corresponding to multiple associated models.  The code I am using is as follows

```
#cohort.rb    

def self.cohort_within_times (from_date, to_date)
  where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?", from_date, to_date)
end


#enrollment.rb

def self.enrollment_within_times (from_date, to_date)
  joins(:cohort) & Cohort.cohort_within_times(from_date, to_date)
end
```

`Cohort` has many `Enrollments`.

When I call `Cohort.cohort_within_times(<valid dates>)` I get a valid response.  However, when I call `Enrollments.enrollments_within_times(<same valid dates>)` I get an empty array as a response.  Full output below:

```
Enrollment.enrollment_within_times("Jan 1st 2013".to_date, "May 31st 2014".to_date)
  Enrollment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "enrollments".* FROM "enrollments" INNER JOIN "cohorts" ON "cohorts"."id" = "enrollments"."cohort_id"
  Cohort Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cohorts".* FROM "cohorts" WHERE (start_date >= '2013-01-01' AND end_date <= '2014-05-31')
=> []
```

How can I get the class method on Enrollment to return the same objects as the Cohort class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you expect:

```
def self.enrollment_within_times(from_date, to_date)
  where(cohort_id: Cohort.cohort_within_times(from_date, to_date).map(&:id))
end
```

or, you could use `joins` method:

```
def self.enrollment_within_times(from_date, to_date)
  joins(:cohort).where('cohorts.start_date >= ? AND cohorts.end_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  As an aside, how can I join multiple tables using the second method?  `Document` belongs to `Enrollment` which, in turn, belongs to `Cohort`.  I've tried to use `joins(:enrollment, :cohort).where('cohorts.start_date >= ? AND cohorts.end_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)` in a `Document` class method but it returns an Active_Record relation when the class methods on `Enrollment` and `Cohort` return arrays.  Do you know how I should be linking the tables?

Comment: I answered my own question.  The correct format is `joins(enrollment: :cohort).where('cohorts.start_date >= ? AND cohorts.end_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)` which I found here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html